# Append function in python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [1.2, 3]])
ser = pd.Series([0, 0], name='r3')    

df_app = df.append(ser)
print('{}\n'.format(df_app))  #has 3 rows

df_app = df.append(ser, ignore_index=True)
print('{}\n'.format(df_app))  #has 3 rows

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[9,9]])
df_app = df.append(df2) 
print(format(df_app))   #didnt understand this part, where did the series row go?
```

OUTPUT

```
0  1
0   5.0  6
1   1.2  3
r3  0.0  0

0  1
0  5.0  6
1  1.2  3
2  0.0  0

0  1
0  5.0  6
1  1.2  3
0  0.0  0
1  9.0  9
```

I didn't understand where did the appended series go in the last append.

df has 2 rows, then [0,0] series is appended =>3 rows
df2 has 2 rows as well, after appending, there is a total of 4 rows. Where did the series row go?

Comment: You need `df_app = df_app.append(df2)` ?

Comment: If add `Series`, added one row, if add DataFrame with 2 rows, are added 2 rows. Can you explian more what is unclear?

Comment: @jezrael after 1st append there were 3 rows in total. But after appending 2nd time which has 2 lists. It is showing 4 rows in total (generally speaking without index). There should be 5 rows after 2nd append. Why only 4 rows?

Comment: Because always append to original `df`? You need `df_app = df_app.append(df2)` for append to `df_app` not to `df`

Comment: isn't df_app like a temporary variable.

Comment: Or is it like appending into original, every time I append? Without making a permanent change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been appending your series to the `df` Dataframe, which will remain same every time.

You are printing the `df_app` dataframe, which is updated over the df only. If you need to append all the rows then instead of appending to `df` you need to append to `df_app` itself.

You should change the code to following:

```
df_app = df_app.append(ser)
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks.